# Sap Hybris - Wro4J Failed to load resource in the cloud - 404 error

Tags: cloud, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront, wro4j

I'm facing a 404 error once enable "storefront.wro4j.enabled" in the cloud. In my local, all files are generated and working fine. I'm not able to find an issue in the cloud.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your storefront buildcallback.xml, remove or comment out below lines:

```xml
<patternset id="extension.trainingstorefront.binary.filter">
  <patternset refid="extension.binary.filter"/>
  <exclude name="resources/wro_addons.xml"/>
</patternset>

<patternset id="extension.trainingstorefront.source.filter">
  <patternset refid="extension.source.filter"/>
  <exclude name="resources/wro_addons.xml"/>
</patternset>

<patternset id="extension.trainingstorefront.production.filter">
  <patternset refid="extension.production.filter"/>
  <exclude name="resources/wro_addons.xml"/>
</patternset>

<patternset id="extension.trainingstorefront.devzip.filter">
  <patternset refid="extension.source.filter"/>
  <exclude name="resources/wro_addons.xml"/>
</patternset>
```

from your buildcallback.xml